# How to properly import a function for use in timeit

Tags: python, timeit

I'm using the timeit function to run some metrics on two methods I've written, and I'm encountering an issue.  See the simplified example files below:

fileA.py, this runs stand alone, and I'm trying to test the function, foo with timeit:

```
if (len(sys.argv) < 2):
    print "Need a command line argument, exiting"
    sys.exit(1)

def foo(n):
    #does some stuff, returns an int
```

This function works fine standalone, I can run it as `./fileA.py 5`

I have a similar file, `fileB.py` that is a different implementation of foo, but is exactly the same except the inside of foo.

Now I have a fileC, where I'm trying to use timeit on both fileA and fileB(fileB part omitted):

```
for n in range(0,10):
    setupStr = 'from fileA import foo'
    setupStr += '; from __main__ import n'
    mytime = timeit.Timer('foo(n)', setupStr)
    timeTaken = mytime.timeit(1)
    print #results, not important
```

The issue that I am getting, is that when I run fileC.py, I get "Need a command line argument, exitng" and it exits.  I understand that this is coming from fileA.py, but why is this portion of code being run at all? I was under the impression that the way timeit works, I am only importing foo from fileA.  Am I assuming wrong?  If so, what would be the best way to rectify this, so that I can test the method `foo(n)` and keep fileA's ability to run standalone with the required command line argument?

Comment: You can also simplify the approach for timing, although it doesn't solve the import problem: directly import the module first, and then use `functools.partial` to create a callable that you pass to `timeit` directly (instead of a string with code in it).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Nifty, I'll be using timeit fairly frequently I think (this is for a course in data structures), so I'll give that a try next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python has to evaluate the whole `fileA` module to resolve `from fileA import foo` - it would be perfectly legitimate to have `foo` be a module-level variable name rather than a function, created by code that would have to be evaluated to get the correct value. To avoid this, wrap the code that's supposed to only be run when `fileA` is being called standalone in:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if (len(sys.argv) < 2):
        ...
```

See the accepted answer to this question for a more detailed explanation:
[What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you! Extra thanks for the link to the detailed explanation.